# How to draw a circle in a sprite in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCSprite with an image Texture. I want to modify this image inserting a circle in a different position at each frame.

I tried to insert a circle overriding draw() method. But it doesn't work for me because i need that the past draws persist while i draw the circle in different positions.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can have another `CCSprite` with a circle texture and just add it as a child to your main `CCSprite` via the `-addChild:` method.

Comment: My main objective is to "draw" with the finger. I could do this way you told me, but my fear is that it consumes too much memory from the device and/or overload the processor, because each time i move my finger in the screen, i would nedd to add a new sprite to the main sprite. Any suggestion??

Comment: Ah yeah, in that case cocos2d is not the way to go. There is a sample project on Apple's developer site that shows how to draw with touches using straight OpenGL ES.